# How to Apache Rewrite URL without redirect?

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

Is it possible to replace a url name like http://mysite.com/sub/ with http://sub.mysite.com using htaccess?

I don't want to make a redirect rather than just to map a sub-directory address to a sub-domain address. So when a person types an address like http//sub.mysite.com/image.jpg this address remains in the browser but it reads the content from http//mysite.com/sub/image.jpg

Comment: I dunno if you can do this with rewriting or not, but the proper way is to use a `VirtualHost` pointed at the subdir you want to be the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Comment: thanks, my problem is that http://mysite.com/sub/ is a virtual directory so the folder "sub" doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you should have root access to the server to start with, you will need to also make some DNS record changes so ensure you have this access also before starting.

I have used both methods previously and they both work, however I found using folders was the winner at the end of the day for our usage, this simplified things significantly for us and we didn't have to worry about changing linkages in scripts, e.g. from http://www.my-site.com/images to http://images.my-site.com depending on the code structure being used.

Instead of typing these long instructions out I am going to give you 2 references that have slightly different approaches depending on if you have a physical folder to use or if it is a variable in the URL. They say it probably as well as I can anyway ;-)

[Physical folder method](http://www.freelinuxtutorials.com/quick-tips-and-tricks/automatic-unlimited-subdomains-via-apache-mod_rewrite/) :: [URL variable method](http://www.reconn.us/content/view/46/67/)

I hope this helps you

Comment: thanks a lot, unfortunately my hosting doesn't support wildcard. I wish there was a simpler way to just rewrite a url name. I can redirect sub.mysite.com to mysite.com/sub but all I need is that a sub-domain remained in the address bar and not a directory.

Comment: Sorry mate, when I read you saying "I don't want to" I thought it was more of a preference than a requirement. Unfortunately the DNS will fail every time a request is made unless the DNS is configured correctly. The only other choice I can think of is (depending on your access level and coding ability) to have a script dynamically writing to the DNS for every change made then using mod_rewrite to dynamically change the URL, this would only work in a server that runs its own DNS though.